# API design terminology, I just can't remember the word!

Tags: api

There's a word that's used in API design that relates to the coupling between two entities. If one entity can vary without impacting the entity they are said to be _ _ _ _ _. For example given the declaration

class Point
  {
    public int X;
    public in Y;
  }

members X and Y could be said to exhibit this behaviour, as a change to X does not lead to any change in Y.
The word I am looking for is not used that much in .NET circles but you'd be hard pressed to read a bokk on C++ STL without coming upon this word repeatedly.

So, after much searching I can't remember this word, can you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orthogonal? Independent?

Answer (score 2):

They are said to be **Loosely-Coupled**.